# PHP Card Game, comparing high cards to get winner

Tags: php, class, oop

I am new to PHP, for learning purposes I am making a simple card game (which I eventually want to turn into black jack) but for now I would just like to compare the two player's cards to see who has the highest set of cards and get the winner that way. I have run into a problem that when I display the php I get a blank screen with no informaiton. ****If I remove the code in "cardgame.php" then I get the cards that the two players have.*** In the error log this is also where an error is shown but I can't figure out what is wrong with that piece of code. There must be something in that piece of code preventing this to work... Any help will be really appreciated.

I will post the four files below:

Card.php

```
class Card
{
    private $suit;
    private $figure;


    public function __construct($Suit, $Fig) {
            $this->suit   = $Suit;
            $this->figure = $Fig;
    }

    public function __toString() {
            return $this->figure . ' of ' . $this->suit;
    }

    public function getFigure() {
            return $this->figure;
    }

    public function getCard() {
            echo $this->figure . " of " . $this->suit . ".<br />";
    }


}

?>
```

Deck.php

```
<?php //can't make objects out of abstract classes, but it's children can
abstract class Deck
{
protected $arrCards; 
protected $listOfCards;

/* abstract methods force classes that extends this class to implement them */
abstract public function dealCard(); //all classes that will inherit will inherit this method


/* already implemented methods */
public function __construct($Cards) {
    $this->arrCards = $Cards;
}

public function shuffleCards() {
    shuffle($this->arrCards);
}

public function listCards() {
    foreach($this->arrCards as $Card) {
        echo $Card . '<br />';
    }
}
}
 ?>
```

EnglishDeck.php

```
<?php
include_once "Deck.php"; 
include_once "Card.php"; 

class EnglishDeck extends Deck
{      
        //perhaps the keys?
    private $suits = array('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades');
    private $cards = array(
    'Ace'=> 1, 
    2 => 2, 
    3 => 3, 
    4 => 4, 
    5 => 5, 
    6 => 6, 
    7 => 7, 
    8 => 8, 
    9 => 9, 
    10 => 10, 
    'Jack' => 10, 
    'Queen'=>10, 
    'King'=>10);

public function dealCard() {
    return array_pop($this->arrCards);
}

public function __construct() {
    $Cards = $this->initEnglishDeck();
    parent::__construct($Cards);
}

function initEnglishDeck() {
    $arrCards = array();

    foreach($this->suits as $Suit) {
        foreach ($this->cards as $Card) {
            $arrCards[] = new Card($Suit, $Card);
        }

    }
    return $arrCards;
}

}

$oBaraja = new EnglishDeck();
$oBaraja->shuffleCards();
?>
```

and cardgame.php

```
   <?php

    include_once "Card.php";
   include_once "EnglishDeck.php";


$oBaraja = new EnglishDeck();
$oBaraja->shuffleCards();


//PLAYER 1
$oP1card1  = $oBaraja->dealCard();
echo("Player one has " . $oP1card1);

 $oP1card2  = $oBaraja->dealCard();
echo(" and a " . $oP1card2 );

$oPlayer1 = $oP1card1 + $oP1card2;

echo "<br>";

//PLAYER 2
$oP2card1  = $oBaraja->dealCard();
echo("Player two has " . $oP2card1);

$oP2card2  = $oBaraja->dealCard();
 echo(" and a " . $oP2card2);

 $oPlayer2 = $oP2card1 + $oP2card2;

 // THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING ERRORS
 $oBaraja->compare($oPlayer1, $oPlayer2) {
    if($oPlayer1 > $oPlayer2){
        echo "Player 1 wins";
    } else if ($oPlayer1 < $oPlayer2) {
        echo "Player 2 wins";
    } else {
        echo "it's a tie";
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: `I display the php I get a blank screen with no informaiton` - This usually indicates that you have disabled error reporting on your web server.  Enable Display Errors in your PHP configuration.  Or consult the error log for the web server.  If there was some bug in the code you should get a useful error message.

Comment: Do you have errors being displayed? If not this should do the trick: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors', 1); ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's walk through it.

```
$oBaraja = new EnglishDeck();
```

You make a new instance of EnglishDeck

```
$oBaraja->shuffleCards();
```

You shuffle the cards

```
public function shuffleCards() {
shuffle($this->arrCards);}
```

But at this point "protected $arrCards;" is still empty. 
You first need to fill it with the cards.

---

Edit
I ran your script, this was the output

```
Notice: Object of class Card could not be converted to int online 18

Player two has 10 of Hearts and a 3 of Diamonds
it's a tie
```

To fix this replace

```
 $oPlayer1 = $oP2card1 + $oP2card2;
```

with

```
 $oPlayer1 = (string)$oP1card1 + (string)$oP1card2;
```

Do the same for $oPlayer2

Also ->compare is not an function.
It does work if you replace

```
$oBaraja->compare($oPlayer1, $oPlayer2) {
if($oPlayer1 > $oPlayer2){
    echo "Player 1 wins";
} else if ($oPlayer1 < $oPlayer2) {
    echo "Player 2 wins";
} else {
    echo "it's a tie";
}
}
```

With

```
if($oPlayer1 > $oPlayer2){
    echo "Player 1 wins";
} else if ($oPlayer1 < $oPlayer2) {
    echo "Player 2 wins";
} else {
    echo "it's a tie";
}
```

or put it in an function called compare($oPlayer1, $oPlayer2) and then call it using $oBaraja->compare($oPlayer1, $oPlayer2)

Comment: hmmm I was thinking the foreach in Deck.php would do tha? :S

Comment: Indeed, but you never call the function. Try setting $oBaraja->shuffleCards(); below $oBaraja = new EnglishDeck();
$oBaraja->shuffleCards(); in your cardgame.php line 10 before //player1

Comment: P.S or set it in deck.php so it get's called automaticly everytime a new instance of deck is created

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but sadly I get the same error: it says it starts with the  $oBaraja->compare($oPlayer1, $oPlayer2) {
    if($oPlayer1 > $oPlayer2){
        echo "Player 1 wins";
    } else if ($oPlayer1 < $oPlayer2) {
        echo "Player 2 wins";
    } else {
        echo "it's a tie";
    }
}